# selenium python 3.7 (Unresolved import: webdriver)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pydev

I want to create a program to log in automatically and all you have to do is put in certain information that the site requests, but I get an error:

`Unresolved import: webdriver`

```py
from selenium import webdriver

name = input("name :")
code = input("code :")

url = ("https://whiteboard.fi")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-rounded btn-block whiteboard-font toggle-modal-button waves-effect waves-light").click()

driver.find_elements_by_name("whiteboard_code").send_keys(code)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-warning waves-effect waves-ligh").click()

driver.find_elements_by_id("student_name").send_keys(name)
driver.find_elements_by_id("oin_room_button").click()

print("done")
```

Comment: did you instal selenium

Comment: yes ( Unresolved import: webdriver )

Comment: Which ide are you using

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: pip freeze and you should see selenium==3.141.0 or some other version. If you don't see it you should install selenium.One way is using pip install selenium cmd